# Pass a variable name to a user written function that uses dyplr

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function that index variables names.
In particular, in my function, I use `mutate` to encode a variable that I have without changing its name. Does anyone knows how I can index a variable on the left end side of mutate?

Here is an example

```
library(tydiverse)
# first create relevant dataset

iris <- iris%>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(mean_Length=mean(Sepal.Length))

# second create my function
userfunction <- function(var){
  newdata <- iris  %>% 
    select(mean_Length,{var}) %>% distinct() %>% 
    mutate(get(var)= # this is what causes my function to fail. How can i refer to the `var` here?
factor(get(var),get(var))) %>% 
arrange(get(var)) # 
  return(newdata)
}
# this function produces the following error # Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

#note that if I change the reference to its original string the function works
userfunction2 <- function(var){
  newdata <- iris  %>% 
    select(mean_Length,{var}) %>% distinct() %>% 
    mutate(Species= # without reference it works, but I am unable to use the function for multiple variables. 
factor(get(var),get(var))) %>% 
arrange(get(var)) # 
  return(newdata)
}
encodedata<- userfunction2("Species")
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `var` is your problem.  I think it's the `=`.  If you you have a `enquo`ted variable on the left hand side of the assignment (which is effectively what you do have with `get()`), you need `:=`, not `=`.

See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for more details.

I would have written your function slightly differently:

```
userfunction <- function(data, var){
  qVar <- enquo(var)
  
  newdata <- data  %>% 
    select(mean_Length,  !! qVar) %>% distinct() %>% 
    mutate(!! qVar := factor(!! qVar, !! qVar)) %>% 
    arrange(!! qVar)  
  return(newdata)
}
```

The inclusion of the `data` parameter means you can include it in a pipe:

```
encodedata <- iris %>% userfunction(Species)
encodedata
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Species [3]
  mean_Length Species   
        <dbl> <fct>     
1        5.01 setosa    
2        5.94 versicolor
3        6.59 virginica
```

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion and change `=` for `:=`but I get the following error `Error: The LHS of := must be a string or a symbol`

Comment: Yes.  You had other issues with your code that I didn't spot first time around.  I've updated my answer to provide proof of a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example that goes into a similar direction as Limey's answer:

```
iris <- datasets::iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(mean_Length=mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  ungroup()

userfunction <- function(var){
  iris  %>%
    transmute(mean_Length, "temp" = iris[[var]]) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    mutate("{var}" := factor(temp)) %>% 
    arrange(temp) %>%
    select(-temp)
}

userfunction("Petal.Length")
```